# Как построить круговую диаграмму отображающую мультиответы?

Tags: excel

У меня есть вариативные данные по этническому составу Канады. Они содержат два варианта: мультиответ, когда человек выбирает несколько вариантов, и один (моно). Например:

```
      мульти ответ Канадцы   10 млн. ч.
      моно ответ   Канадцы    5 млн. ч.
      мульти ответ Англичане  5 млн.ч.
      моно ответ   Англичане  1 млн. ч.
```

И т.д.

Я хочу построить круговую диаграмму, которая бы сумела отобразить такую структуру данных. Я такой функции не нашел, поэтому наваял в Инкскейпе примерно как это может выглядеть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть каждая группа должна принадлежать к одному сектору, просто показываясь различными оттенками. Это вообще возможно? И если нет, какие еще варианты Вы посоветуете?

Comment: Еще важное дополнение - мульти ответ означает, что человек назвался канадцем и англичанином или еще кем либо (то есть один и тот же человек фигурирует в мультиответе "канадцы" и "англичане").

Answer (score 0):

В таблице подготовить данные. Нужны два значения: *total-singl* и *singl*. Сумма этих двух значений - величина *total*, которая будет отображена двумя секторами диаграммы.

Выделить диапазон *названия/значения*, закладка *Вставка-Диаграммы-Круговая*, ввставить диаграмму.

Двойной клик на секторе (или выделить сектор, правый клик на секторе), *Формат_**точки**_данных-Заливка*. Здесь внимательно: если сектор не выбран, будут форматироваться все сектора (*Формат_ряда_данных*).

Выбрать тип заливки и цвет. Можно один цвет для двух секторов, но с разной прозрачностью.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для корректного отображения в легенде можно написать *total-singl*

Можно добавить подписи данных и указать, какие данные отображать.

Если данные динамичны и размещение секторов будет меняться, то средствами *Excel* менять цвт автоматически не получится. Нужно задействовать *VBA*.

Comment: То есть это все равно будут разные не налаживающиеся сектора? Дело в том что так как каждое total перекликается с несколькими значениями (если человек назвался и канадцем, и англичанином, то он попадает соответственно и в группу тотал канадцы и в группу тотал англичане). А таких групп несколько, если каждую отображать, то там далеко за сто процентов выйдет, что противоестественно для круговой диаграммы.

Comment: А это совсем непонятно... Если человек в разных группах, то и значения в разных группах... Тут уже не о диаграмме речь, а о Ваших исходных данных. Как их предоставите диаграмме, так она и скушает.

Answer (score 0):

Вот данные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, если сложить все значения в %, то получается выше 100, так как это - мультиответы, то есть один и тот же челове по сути попадает в несколько групп. Может имеет смысл применить какой-то другой вид диаграмм?

Comment: Если это мультиответы, то что здесь *total*? Сумма всех значений? Тогда где второй (третий)  *total*? Как понять, где и какие группы перекрываются?

Comment: Total эту полное число каждой этногруппы, включая мультиответы и сингл. Сингл - это часть каждой такой группы. Но в целом, я в начале вопроса действительно упустил важную деталь - должны перекрываться не только сингл с мульти, но и мульти с мульти. То есть, надо знать, сколько человек назвались русскими канадцами, английскими  канадцами, и.тд. То есть, задача куда сложнее, чем я предполагал заранее. Таких данных у меня нет, а если бы и были, как устроить, чтобы все эти сектора перекрывали друг друга, непонятно.

Comment: Вот если бы были исходные данные... А так - разговор ни о чем. Если Вы не можете нормально сформулировать задачу, то как Вам могут помочь другие?

Comment: Даже если бы были Вы бы не решили эту задачу.  Мульти ответ означает, что человек может одновременно назваться и канадцем, и кем то еще. Значит, все рассматриваемые группы должны между собой пересекаться. Я хотел, чтобы все эти цифры влезли в         100%  круговую диаграмму. А в Excel насколько я понял это сделать не получится. А вопрос, я признаю, изначально поставил неправильно.

Comment: Как можно из >100% сделать 100%, если нет  информации по пересечениям? Кого объединять в одном секторе? Без данных по пересечениям задача нерешаема. Не только в Excel, но и логически. А вот с нужными данными задача решаема.